# How can i set ko.bindingHandlers value

Tags: knockout.js

```
ko.bindingHandlers.translate = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var translateTo = bindingContext.$data.domain._latestValue;
            console.log(translateTo);// output : work
            //my wuestion is how can i set this in html
           }
    };
```

**HTML:**

```
 <span data-bind="translate: domain"></span><!--this is not working-->
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. If you want to access the value from inside the custom binding you just need to do: valueAccessor() and that'll give you the value to "translate:".

Comment: $(element).text(translateTo); use this to setvalue in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to fill is "update" method, and access the model directly from valueAccessor. You don't need to use bindingContext since your binding is fairly simple.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.translate = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var domain = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var translateTo = ko.unwrap(domain._latestValue);
        element.textContent = translateTo;
    }
};
```

Comment: i tested with my data. but i would need to see your data in full js code.

Comment: $(element).text(translateTo); is working fine thank you for your help